# Solving time complexity of merge sort

Tags: computational-complexity, recursive-algorithms

I was asked to prove that the time complexity of merge sort is $ O(log_2n)$ but I cannot find a way to continue my method. Any help?

$T(n)=2T(\frac{n}{2} )+n$

$T(n)= 2[2T(\frac{n}{4})+n] +n = 4T(\frac{n}{4})+3n$

$T(n)=8T(\frac{n}{8})+7n$

$...$

$...$

$...$

$...$

$T(n)= 2^kT(\frac{n}{2^k})+(2^k-1)n$

Finally $\frac{n}{2^k}=1$ and $\therefore n=2^k$

I do not know how to continue from here to prove that it is $O(log_2n)$

Comment: Are you sure it's not $O(nlog_{2}n)$?

Comment: In your second line, $T\left(\frac n2\right)$ should be $\left[2T\left(\frac n4\right) + \frac n2\right]$.

Comment: @RobertChamberlain - it is O(nlog_2n). I just don't know how to get it from what I have done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$T(n)=2T(\frac{n}{2} )+n$

$T(n)= 2[2T(\frac{n}{4})+\color{red}{\frac n2}] +n = 4T(\frac{n}{4})+\color{red}2n$

$T(n)=8T(\frac{n}{8})+\color{red}3n$

$...$

$T(n)= 2^kT(\frac{n}{2^k})+\color{red}kn$

Finally $\frac{n}{2^k}=1$ and $\therefore n=2^k$

Comment: okay then what should be done? How can I get O(nlogn) from this?

Comment: $nT(1)+kn$ is $n\log n$.

Comment: :( I still don't see how that relates

Comment: What is $k$ ???

Comment: $k=log_2n$ So that gives me $T(n) = nT(1)+nlog_2n$ If T(1) is a constant, i get $O(nlog_2n)$ is that so?

Comment: Can the same method be used to prove for a $\Omega (g(x))$ of a function?

Comment: Yep, $T(1)$ is a constant, and the linear term is absorbed by the linlog term. The recurrence method is used to establish $T(n)$. Then the solution of the recurrence can be given in terms of big-$O$ or big-$\Omega$. But in this particular case, it was possible to obtain the exact solution.